# tea tastes / smells slightly acidic

Tags: tea

I have been drinking some houjicha and I have brewed it today but it seems to smell and taste slightly acidic. Is this normal / healthy?

Storage: foil lined zip lock bag

Brewing: 75C, 1 tbsp for 2 large cups

Comment: In addition to the answer below, it's worth noting that hojicha is a fully roasted tea, and sometimes improper roasting can make the resulting tea seem bitter, astringent, and acidic. This sometimes just happens, and if you're struggling with it, I would consider buying hojicha from a different source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your water's not hot enough.

It's not a tea I've tried myself, so a little google-fu was employed to find the consensus is boiling water, for one minute steep/brew/mash.

I found similar instructions in many places, but this was the most comprehensive, from [letsdrinktea.com - Houjicha Guide](https://letsdrinktea.com/types-of-tea/green-tea/houjicha/)

> Brewing Instructions
>
> - Pour some boiling water into the empty teapot to warm it up. Discard the water and dry the teapot.
> - Put one heaping teaspoon of tea leaves into the teapot for each cup you plan to make.
> - Pour the exact amount of boiling water into the teapot that you will need to fill the cups. You do not want to leave any water in the
>   teapot after the cups are filled.
> - Let the leaves steep for one minute.
> - Pour a small amount of tea into the first cup, then pour the same amount into every other cup. Continue filling the cups a little at a
>   time, making sure that each cup contains the same amount of the weaker
>   first pours and the stronger last drops. DO NOT fill one cup
>   completely and then move on to the next cup.
> - Continue pouring until the teapot is completely empty. You want the leaves to be as dry as possible to ensure a quality second infusion
> - With most types, you will get two or three good infusions. For the second, repeat the steps above. For the third, double the steeping
>   time.